# How to find file named something in an folder

Tags: node.js, fs

So like I want to find a js file named "cola" in a folder named "legos" how do I do that in fs

Comment: What is your _specific_ question?

Comment: how do i find a file named "cola" in a folder named "lego"  using FS

Comment: That's not very specific. You're basically just asking someone to write your code for you. What have you tried so far? What don't you understand about using `fs`?